# Marx was truly a "tough guy"

Tags: indefinite-article

*Marx – ladies and gents – was truly a "tough guy".*

Is this sentence OK? I mean the postition of the indefinite article? Why is it not placed before the word "truly" as in the sentence "he was a very tough guy"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author does not mean that Marx was *a truly tough guy* (= a very tough guy) but that he was *truly* (in truth, in fact) a tough guy and not something else (which is presumably described elsewhere in the discourse—for instance, a sentimental do-gooder or an armchair theorist).

Comment: I think it would be at least very least "odd" to apply modifiers like ***truly, really, very,*** to the specific word ***tough*** in OP's cited context, because of the scare quotes - which to my mind imply the enclosed term should be treated as a single semantic unit (within which you can't naturally abstract one component for modification). Not that this would be apparent in *speech*, so essentially it's a matter of orthography. Offhand I can't think of any similar two-word collocation where this "indivisible semantic unit" principle would apply even if there *weren't* any scare quotes.